# R: split dataframe by multiple answers

Tags: r

So I have a dataframe with results of the survey.
The thing is, I have several questions with multiple answers in cell.
For example:

```
q1|q2
answer1;answer2;ansert4 |1986
```

so I need to extract 'tidy' dataset for specific analysis tasks, meaning: split those cells down  in the same column and copy other specified columns so it will be like that:

```
q1|q2
answer1|1986
answer2|1986
answer4|1986
```

How can i do this in R? 
I am pretty sure it is a simple task, but I don't have any clue...

Answer (score 6):

Another similar solution would be

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "q1", sep = ";", direction = "long")
#         q1   q2
# 1: answer1 1986
# 2: answer2 1986
# 3: ansert4 1986
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `data.table` package and `strsplit` function:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,setNames(strsplit(q1, ';'),'q1'),by=q2]
#     q2       q1
#1: 1986  answer1
#2: 1986  answer2
#3: 1986 ansert4
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(q1 = "answer1;answer2;ansert4 ", q2 = 1986L), .Names = c("q1", 
"q2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: You should probably mention GitHub somewhere here

Comment: I think I really did not get it..! What's the point with Git?

Comment: Oh never mind, I thought you've used the `tstrsplit` function from the devel version. Either way, you can also do this `setDT(df)[, .(q1 = tstrsplit(q1, ';')), by = q2]` using the devel version.